# Unable to get data from Express server to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from express to react using fetch API. The express server is reading data from a postgresql server and should send that data to the React application.

Front-end (React) code -

```
const query = 'select * from "LabResults"';

const executeQuery = async () => {
        console.log('Running execute query')
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/execute-query?query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`);
            const result = await response.json();
            console.log('Printing result fetched from DB ', response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error executing query:', error);
        }
    };
```

Backend (Express) code (server.js) -

```
app.get(api_endpoint, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // console.log(req);
        // const { query } = req.query;
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM "LabResults"';
        if (!query) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Query parameter is required.' });
        }
        const result = await pool.query(query);
        console.log(result.rows)
        const data = { message: 'Hello from the server!' };
        res.send(data);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Error executing query 1:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}/${api_endpoint}`);
});
```

I am facing the following 2 challenges -

1. Ideally I want to send the query from React app to Express server, hence I am passing it encoded to *fetch*. However, server responds with invalid query error. What is the right way to pass the query?
2. Since I was stuck on 1, I assumed a valid query is being sent to the server by hardcoding the query in the express server itself. I am able to poll the DB and get the data which prints correctly on console (it's an array of objects if it matters as I am printing all the rows). Then I have to return this to the React app, I send it to React using `res.send(data)`. I had tried `res.json(data)` and `res.send(JSON.stringify(data))` before but none of these is working. In the React app, I get the error shown in the below image - it is happening due to the line `const result = await response.json();` but I don't understand what is going wrong.

Note: Since I was unable to send the actual rows back to the React app, I thought of mocking that data too (`const data = { message: 'Hello from the server!' };`), but even that is not working and gives the same error.

[image]

**UPD**: Adding package.json files for both server and client below.

Attaching below `package.json` for server

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.3"
  }
}
```

Attaching below package.json for client (react) -

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.114.0",
    "@fluentui/react-hooks": "^8.6.34",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.18.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.68",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not good prcatice to send sql queries. Someone can send 'drop database dbname' . About question: Do you see console.log message at server when initiate api request? And try comment const result = await response.json() in frontend.

Comment: You should let the backend do the "thinking" and the frontend do the "displaying". Sending query from frontend is a bit... unconventional. Anyway, `res.json(data)` should have worked, what's the error that you got from doing so?

Comment: @LãNgọcHải error is attached in the picture in the question. Front end needs to perform various operations on the postgres db, hence I am passing the query. What is the correct/better way to go about this?

Comment: @user1852788 there is no error coming up at server. At the server URL, the message is printing nicely, with no console errors. Error is coming at front-end side which I have attached in the image. The returned object is not JSON i think.

Comment: @user1852788 What's the exact result of `console.log(response)` in frontend? Maybe it's really not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the client and server were hosted on different ports, but somehow the client was making the API call at the client port (instead of server port).

To fix this, I set up CORS on the server and set up a proxy in `package.json` of client (React) to redirect all API calls to the server port.